# DNS for Development Servers

Tags: dns, development-environment

I have an app running on 1 web and 2 worker production servers (AWS).  Now, I would like to continue to develop without interrupting the production servers using 3 of the cheapest AWS tier servers in the same configuration (1 web and 2 workers).

Is there a way to use an "Alternative DNS service" to point my browser and the workers here while testing?  Essentially, its intentional DNS Spoofing.

Consider this Pseudocode on the Worker:

```
if (iAmInDevelopment) {
    dnsServer = alternativeDns;
}
```

Is this possible?  And is this a good way to separate production and development?  I like it because then all my SSL Certs, paths, etc remain exactly the same and the only change is to the DNS, therefore the code would be tested very close to a production configuration.